# SQL - получение данных из нескольких таблиц

Tags: php, mysql, sql

В общем, есть три базы -

> members - [id, cid, uid]

```
---------------------
```

> dialogs - [id, type, name]

```
---------------------
```

> users - [id, nickname].

Моя задача - получить данные. 
Сначала получаем сам диалог(SQL ниже):

```
SELECT
dialogs.id,
dialogs.type,
dialogs.name,
FROM
dialogs,
members
WHERE
members.uid = "'.$my_id.'" AND
dialogs.id = members.cid
```

Но, далее мне нужно чтобы если dialogs.type = 0(личное сообщение), у меня получался ещё один мембер - members.cid = id_полученного_раннее_диалога, members.uid != "'.$my_id.'".

Comment: А что мешает вам сделать это все с помощью массивов через PHP ?? Выбрать данные тремя запросами и через условия PHP прогнать. Почему вы хотите делать подобное через SQL ??

Comment: Всему виной ограниченность времени и число диалогов.

Comment: Не очень понятно, что всё же требуется. Попробуйте показать на примере, что ли. *есть три базы* Это таблицы. *получался ещё один мембер* В какой форме? Структура выходного набора должна быть неизменной.

Comment: @alexsis20102 *что мешает вам сделать это все с помощью массивов через PHP ??* Вот зачем делать на PHP то, для чего предназначен MySQL и не предназначен PHP? То, что Вы знаете PHP лучше, чем MySQL - хреновенькое обоснование...

Comment: @ТипаКодер, ... *WHERE (members.uid = "'.$my_id.'" AND dialogs.id = members.cid and dialogs.type<>0) OR (members.cid=dialogs.id and members.uid!="$my_id" and dialogs.type=0)*